# Sequelize TypeScript returns a wrong number of items when calling findAll() on model factory

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize to query my items from the local Postgres database, then I found something really scary.

I just query all database entries of a specific model using:

```
model.findAll({attributes: ["columnName"]}).then((data) => {
console.log(data.length); // logged: 800
});
```

Everything looks good, but then I went and bind the Postgres datasource directly from my IDE, opened a console from there and ran the same query to validate the overall number of items returned from Sequelize:

```
select count(*) from tableOfModel; # returned: 600
```

I got a shock from that moment as the number of items I was getting was only a total of **600** items and was different from what I got with Sequelize.

What might be wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any condition in your `defaultScope` of the model?

Comment: Hi, there are no conditions in the default scope, why ?

Comment: The answer does not go into detail, so this question can be closed under the official reason of "typo/unrepro".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the error was: a collaborator changed the database configuration without telling me so, so the database was remotely hosted on server, so everything was okay with Sequelize. I should have noticed it at first :).